# Unreachable statement error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why do I get an unreachable statement error when I compile my code. The error comes on the last line of code (`System.out`). It is inside the main method and I don't see why it isn't reachable.

```
public class Count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector numberList = new Vector();
        double randomNum;

        //for loop to get numbers and add to vector
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++) {
            do {
                randomNum = Math.random();
            } while (randomNum < .01 || randomNum > .99);

            //takes the random number, rounds it, and multiplies it by 100
            //so that the numbers go from 1 to 99
            Math.round(randomNum *= 100);
            //converts the double to an int
            int tempNum = (int) randomNum;
            //the vector is built
            numberList.add(i, tempNum);
        }

        //sorts numbers
        Collections.sort(numberList);

        int count[] = new int[99];

        for (int j = 1;; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
                if ((numberList.elementAt(i)) == j) {
                    count[j] += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outer `for` loop doesn't have an ending conditional:

```
for(int j=1;;j++){
```

`j` will increment indefinitely. You're likely looking for:

```
for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++) {
```

Comment: thanks... that solved it. now I get an index out of bounds error. haha ughhhh

Comment: @user2012751 Array index starts from 0. so change `j=1` to `j=0`.

Comment: `count[99]` is outside the bounds for your array. The highest would be `count[98]` since arrays begin at 0.

Comment: what im trying to do is write a program that generates 10000 numbers ranging from 1 to 99 and each number has to be counted

Answer (score 1):

There's no condition in your for loop 
      for(int j=1;;j++){

More like  for(int j=1;j<1000;j++){ fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((numberList.elementAt(i)) == j)
```

Incompatible operand types Object and int.

Seems like the above code is never be executed.